# sql server query- converting postgres to ms sql server db

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is the `postgressql` query:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp(rolloffdate,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'Month YYYY') period, * from employeedetails WHERE EMPLOYEE_STATUS > 3 
ORDER BY to_timestamp(rolloffdate,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Can anyone please convert this into `microsoft sql server 2008`. It states that `to_char` and `to_timestamp` is not a built in function name

Comment: Unrelated, but: what data type is `rolloffdate`? If that is already a date or timestamp, then calling `to_timestamp` on it is completely useless (in fact it's a bug waiting to happen). If it's _not_ a timestamp, then the question is: why are you storing timestamps in a varchar column?

Comment: roll off date is of datetime data type. And i have removed timestamp it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), rolloffdate, 101) AS Period, *
FROM employeedetails
WHERE EMPLOYEE_STATUS > 3 
ORDER BY Period
```